# Opening and reading file from argv

Tags: c++, xcode, file, input

Say for example the command line is:

```
./myprogram my_input.txt
```

So I understand argv[1] is my_input.txt

What I want to do is be able to read in from this .txt file in my program and initialize some variables based on what was read in.

Let's just say this txt file has the following:

1 2 3

So in my xcode program I have:

```
ifstream myFile(argv[1]);
int a, b, c;
while (myFile >> a >> b >> c){
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";
}
myFile.close();

cout << "made it here\n";
```

Is this the proper syntax? I'm working on xcode, which I'm a little unfamiliar with. In edit schemes, in arguments passed on launch, I have "my_input.txt". And on my computer I have this txt file in the same directory as my .cpp program. However I'm unable to read in in from the file. Any help would be appreciated!

the while loop is being skipped when I exit my code and I don't understand why. The only thing outputted is the "made it here".

Comment: you should pass the file correctly

Comment: then check whether the file opened successfully or not: `if(myFile.is_open()) cout << "Opened successfully" else cout << "Failed to open file" << argv[1] << endl; `

Comment: I got it to work now. For some reason when I compile through linux it works just fine. When I compile through xcode the file isn't being read in correctly.

Comment: so add the full path of the file not just the name and retry

Comment: Thank you Raindrop!

Comment: welcome! did it work?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much sir